# Jekyll redirect entire directory

Tags: redirect, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I want to redirect `/old/folder/struct/*` to `/new/fold/struc/*`.

I know that jekyll runs at compile time so it can't really catch the URLs at runtime. I'm looking for a creative workaround.

And preferably, one that would work on GitHub Pages (which means htaccess is not possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using a simple [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh), built into my default layout file.

You need to do this for every single file, though. There's no "catch-all" solution.

---

Simple example layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
    {% if page.redirect %}<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url={{ page.redirect }}">{% endif %}
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
    {% if page.redirect %}<h3> Redirecting to <a href="{{ page.redirect }}">{{ page.redirect }}</a> ...</h3>{% endif %}
    {{ content }}
</body>
</html>
```

- The line in the `<head>` will do the actual redirect.
- The line in the body just shows a nice message in case the redirect doesn't work.

With a layout file like this, you can create a file that will redirect to another URL with just two lines of YAML front-matter:

```
---
layout: default
redirect: /new/fold/struc/foo.html
---
```

That's all.
As I said in the beginning: you need to do this for each of the hundreds of files in the old folder.
I had the same problem as well, so I wrote a one-off script to do it.

---

I've also written a blog post about this approach:
[Easy meta redirects with Jekyll](http://christianspecht.de/2014/09/15/easy-meta-redirects-with-jekyll/)

Comment: Did you by any chance keep that one-off script?

Comment: No, I didn't, because I just needed it one single time. But you can easily write your own in the language of your choice *(mine was C#)*. It's just: 1. Loop all files in the folder 2. Overwrite the content of the file with the front-matter shown above 3. Replace the path by your new directory and append the file name

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [jekyll-redirect-from](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from).

Just add to your **_config.yml**:

```
gems:
 - jekyll-redirect-from
```

Or add it to your **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'jekyll-redirect-from'
```

Then for any page or post you want to redirect:

```
title: My amazing post
redirect_from:
  - /old/folder/struct
  - /new/fold/struct
```

I do notice you have a wildcard, so there may be some other URLS under  the older folder structure, in which case I would recommend doing a find and replace in your project.

### Example for Posts

This works under the condition that you have a setting with the path to the old path. In this case this was an old Blogger post which has **blogger_orig_url** with the old URL.

This example redirects the path to the html file to Jekyll's new URL format.

I don't think there's an easy solution within Jekyll, as it primarily generates a static website.

In terms of find and replace, you'll need to search for text/instances where the old path exists and change it to the new path-- basically add the **redirect_from**.

Sample post in _posts/ folder:

```
---
layout: post
title: 'My New Post'
date: '2005-01-04T10:29:00.002-06:00'
author: John Doe
tags:
- Music
modified_time: '2005-01-11T04:05:03.224-06:00'
thumbnail: http://foobar.com/foo.jpg
blogger_orig_url: http://www.foobar.com/2005/01/my-new-post.html
redirect_from: /2005/01/my-new-post.html
---

Sample text here. This post should be under path /2005/01/my-new-post/.
```

*I don't know exactly what your posts/pages have or look like, I did something like this example when I converted an old Blogger posts to Jekyll's and didn't want to break the old links to my posts.*

Comment: Can I use variables in the FrontMatter? Like, /old/{{page.url}} ? Because then I could make it into a layout file...

Comment: @NathanH I'm not sure about support for something like that.

Comment: I have hundreds of items under those folders, I'm looking for a way to save time...

Comment: "I would recommend doing a find and replace", what would you replace? Each file would need a different url since you need to give the full path every time...